# Significant Delays Occur When Loading Settings, Nautilus, and Terminal After Booting Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: 23.10

The title explains my issue. Additionally, despite having dark mode enabled, everything appears in light mode. However, after a while, dark mode starts working again.